# How to get the access product ID in Shopify?

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am trying to make the inventory quantity appear on a Shopify website, and so far can console.log the entire object, but I am stuck on how to I grab the individual product ID when the select dropdown changes?
This Shopify theme I am working with does not have the ?variant={variant.id} in the Shop URL, like most modern themes do.

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<form class="product-form" id="product-form" action="/cart/add" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product-id="{{product.id}}">
                <div id="product-variants">
                  <select id="product-select" name="id" style="display: none;">
                    {% for variant in product.variants %}
                    {% if variant.available %}
                    <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}</option>
                    {% else %}
                    <option disabled="disabled">
                      {{ variant.title }} - {{'products.product.sold_out' | t}}
                    </option>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                  </select>
                </div>
```

.........

```
 {% assign current_variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
               <div class="live-inventory">
                 <p class="live-inventory-count">We have {{ current_variant.inventory_quantity }} in stock </p>
               </div>
```

...........

```
<script>
    let customObject = {}
    {%  for var in product.variants %}
        customObject[{{- var.id -}}] = {
        inventoryQuantity : {{ var.inventory_quantity }}
   }
    {%  endfor %}

 
  let currentSelectedVariantProduct = customObject[variantId];
  //how to accesss my customObject variantId without being in the for-loop up above???
  //just need to get the id then this would work.

  console.log(currentSelectedVariantProduct, 'I AM IN PRODUCT.LIQUID')

  const variantSelectorElement = document.querySelector('#product-variants');
  variantSelectorElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const liveInventoryCount = document.querySelector('.live-inventory-count')
    liveInventoryCount.innerHTML = currentSelectedVariantProduct.inventoryQuantity 
  })

 
</script>
```

customObject looks like this when outputted:

```
{
    "30280335163469": {
        "inventoryQuantity": 46
    },
    "18515284230": {
        "inventoryQuantity": 21
    },
    "30280354070605": {
        "inventoryQuantity": 66
    },
    "30280337981517": {
        "inventoryQuantity": 17
    },
    "18515284294": {
        "inventoryQuantity": 18
    },
    "30280354693197": {
        "inventoryQuantity": 32
    }
}
```

Am very stuck on how to access the var.id outside of the for-loop.